# Microsoft Virtual WiFi Adapter Missing from Device Manager/Network Connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, drivers

I have Windows 8.1 with Realtek RTL8187SE and I wanted to start a WiFi access point from my laptop but I checked on the Device Manager and "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Adapter" was missing. I clicked "Show hidden devices" but I couldn't find it under "Network Adapters". I tried disabling my WiFi adapter and re-enabling it to see if Microsoft Virtual WiFi Adapter would appear but nothing happened. I uninstalled and reinstalled my driver by restarting the laptop but it didn't show up. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** I almost forgot, I checked Network Connections to see if I would find it but it isn't there.

**EDIT 2:** I used the following command to attempt to create the hotspot.

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=***** key=*********
>
> netsh wlan start hostednetwork

And it said "The hosted network could not be started".
I also tried

> netsh wlan show drivers | findstr "Hosted network supported"

But it said that  hosted network is not supported even though I created hotspots on Windows Vista/7.

Comment: What did you do to create it?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I'll edit the question

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Edited.